# nested cursors in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor

i have temporary table created in stored procedure with 52600 records, i wanted to iterate  the temporary table and update a column for each row.

here i have two `cursors` one for temp table and second for other table say table2 which has three rows, i have to take 1 row from temp table and iterate through table2 and compare,if matching found iam updating a column in temp table.

this process is taking lot of time approximately 500 sec, is it good to do it in `stored procedure` using cursors and loops or is it good to do it in code ?

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_repaymentDelay`()
BEGIN
    drop table if exists loan_repayed_temp;
    create temporary table loan_repayed_temp ( l_id int primary key, loan_Id int, installmentNo int,date_Diff int,interval_id int default 0);

insert into loan_repayed_temp (l_id,loan_Id,installmentNo,date_Diff) 

     select  lrs.id ,lrs.loan_profile_id ,lrs.installment_number , datediff(curdate(), lrs.estimated_payment_date) from 
 loanTable lp inner join loanrepaymentschedule lrs on lp.id = lrs.loan_profile_id and lp.state = 'REPAYMENT_IN_PROGRESS'
 left join repayments r on lrs.loan_profile_id = r.loan_profile_id and r.repayment_number = lrs.installment_number 
 where r.loan_profile_id is null and lrs.estimated_payment_date < NOW()  

;

    BEGIN
        declare done int default false;

        declare lid, loanId, installmentNo , dateDiff int;
        declare cursor2 cursor for select id, interval_range_min, interval_range_max from delay_interval;
        declare cursor1 cursor for select l_id,loan_Id, installmentNo,date_Diff from loan_repayed_temp;

        declare continue handler for not found set done = true;

       open cursor1;

            cursor1_loop : loop

                fetch cursor1 into lid, loanId, installmentNo, dateDiff;

                IF done THEN
                LEAVE cursor1_loop;
                END IF;


          --    delay interval comparision --

                BEGIN
                    declare i , min ,max int;
                    declare done2 int default false;
                    declare continue handler for not found set done2 = true;

                    open cursor2;

                    cursor2_loop: loop

                            fetch cursor2 into i, min, max;

                            IF done2 THEN
                            LEAVE cursor2_loop;
                            end IF;



                                if dateDiff >= min and dateDiff <= max then



                            --    insert into datedemo values(dateDiff,loanId,i);


                                 update loan_repayed_temp set interval_id = i where l_id = lid; 

                                    leave cursor2_loop;

                                end if; 



                        end loop cursor2_loop; 

                    close cursor2;
                END; 

                -- --



                end loop cursor1_loop;



        close cursor1;

    END; 



    drop table  loan_repayed_temp;
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your cursor correctly, your looping through all the records in your temp table and seeing if the date_diff field is between the min and max of the delay_interval table.  If so, I think this would work the same way and should be a lot quicker:

```
UPDATE loan_repayed_temp l
    INNER JOIN delay_interval d
        ON l.date_Diff >= d.interval_range_min
            AND l.date_Diff <= interval_range_max
SET l.interval_id = d.id
```

Here is a sample [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2f7c/1).  Do let me know if I misunderstood.

Good luck.